# Interpret c# lambda syntax

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a general understanding of Lambda expressions but not sure what the `() =>` syntax means.  This code appears to return a list of Task items but I'm unsure how it executes or how to interpret what it means.

Can someone tell me:

1. what does `() =>` mean?
2. It appears that each of the `new Task` blocks are executed sequentially?

```
 private DateTime? _myTime = null;
 private DateTime? _theirTime = null;
 private bool _okToProcess = true;

 List<Task> myTasks = new List<Task>
            {
                   new Task( () => 
                    {
                        _myTime = GetMyTime();
                    }),

                     new Task( () => 
                    {
                        _theirTime = GetTheirTime(); 
                        _okToProcess = _myTime > _theirTime;                                         
                    }),

                new Task(() => 
                    {
                        if (_okToProcess)
                        {
                           WriteToMyLogStep("We are processing");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           WriteToMyLogStep("We are NOT processing");
                        }
                     });
            };
```

Comment: 1: the action to be executed; 2: the tasks are only defined, not executed.

Comment: You shouldn't ask two distinct questions at the same time. Next time, actually post two different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`()` - represents the parameters taken by the anonymus method,

`=>` - is generally read **goes to** and points to the anonymus methods body that uses those parameters (if any provided).

In your case the lamda expression is the same as:

```
 delegate() {  _myTime = GetMyTime(); }
```

As for the Tasks they are just added to a list, they are not executed. How they will be executed depends on how you want to execute them in the future. (maybe in a loop on the same thread or maybe on different threads).

Comment: I'm not sure if explaining lambdas using the old `delegate` syntax (which is not used much) is helpful.

Comment: well, old delegate syntax resembles more to a normal method compared to lambdas, thus you can get a better picture. I'm talking from an unexperienced point of view. wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Great answer Freeman!... and this helped me to better understand this syntax and put things in perspect.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `() =>` syntax just means that there's no named input to the lambda. It is like calling a method that takes no parameters.

As for the code the tasks are just created but never actually started, so they don't run in the code shown. I assume the list is enumerated and the tasks started somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRasmussen. Each task **IS** executed using the Start method later in the code thru an enumeration of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably used to seeing lambda functions like `x => DoSomething(x)`.  That's actually shorthand for `(x) => DoSomething(x)` - the initial `(x)` represents the parameters to the function, the same as the `(x)` in `DoSomething(x)`. does.

In this case, there are no parameters, so it uses `()`, the same as a regular function would be `DoSomething()`.

As for the `Task`s, they'll run in parallel once started, unless you explicitly wait until each one is done before starting the next.

Comment: thx for the clarification... (the Tasks) "they'll run in parallel once started, unless you explicitly wait until each one is done". Correct, each task is started in an enumeration like:  task.Start;  task.Wait();

Answer (score 0):

() would be similar to the parameters the function takes, and I believe that tasks are executed asynchronously
=> Points to the body of the function

Answer (score 0):

1. The anonymous Action to be executed;
2. The tasks are only defined, not executed.

Answer (score 0):

`()=>` is an `Action` - an expression with no parameters.

These tasks have not been started so (currently) will never complete...

Answer (score 0):

1. `()` is your list of parameters, in your case empty or none, that is getting passed into the anonymous function following the `=>` operator. The `=>` gets its name from Lambda calculus.
2. It depends on how you are calling your tasks in the list. This is simply a `List<Task>` with Tasks in it. In order to execute your tasks you would need to do something like this:

   ```
   foreach (Task t in myTasks) {
       t.RunSynchronously();  // in this case the tasks would run synchronously
   }
   ```